# Couldn't match expected type 'SomeEntity’ with actual type ‘Key SomeEntity’

Tags: haskell, yesod, template-haskell

Hi I am a beginner in Haskell and Yesod and I need help with this problem.

These are my entities:

```
Location
    name Text sqltype=varchar(255)
    address AddressId Maybe sqltype=varchar(255)
    UniqueLocationName name
    deriving Show Typeable

Manifestation
    name Text sqltype=varchar(255)
    description Text Maybe sqltype=varchar(255)
    category Category Maybe
    startDateTime UTCTime sqltype=DateTime
    location LocationId Maybe sqltype=varchar(255)
    UniqueManName name
    deriving Show Typeable
```

This is my handler that calls the man-details template:

```
getManDetailsR :: ManifestationId -> Handler Html
getManDetailsR mid = do
    (_, user) <- requireAuthPair
    md <- runDB $ get404 mid -- type is Manifestation
    defaultLayout $ do
        setTitle "Manifestation details"
        $(widgetFile "man-details")
```

And part of the man-details hamlet file where I want to display information about the event:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="project-info-box mt-0">
                <h2>#{manifestationName md}
                <p class="mb-0">#{fromJust(manifestationDescription md)}

            <div class="project-info-box">
                <p><b>Start :</b>{show $ manifestationStartDateTime md}
                <p><b>Location :</b>#{locationName (manifestationLocation md)}
```

In this case error is :
Couldn't match expected type ‘Location’
with actual type ‘Maybe (Key Location)’

Then I try like this :

```
$maybe l <- manifestationLocation md
                    <p><b>Location :</b>{locationName l}
```

And error is :
Couldn't match expected type ‘Location’
with actual type ‘Key Location’

I apologize for the huge question, but I don't know how to get out of this, ie how to get only the value out of this pair (Key Location)?
Any advice and help is welcome,
Thanks.

Comment: `l` contains the `Key` of a `Location`, not the `Location` itself, for that you will need another query.

Comment: Do you want to tell me that it is impossible to get to the location like this?
Do I have to run the runDB once again, now with mid (id of manifestation) in the handler to get the location of that manifestation and then use it in the template?

Comment: If so, then my relation between the Location and the Manifestation is not what I need.
I need to make a many to many relation so I can get Location from Manifestation?

Answer (score 0):

I'll post my solution, it's a beginner's problem, but it might be useful to someone.
As @Willem Van Onsem wrote in the comment, I again made a query to the database
now for a location.
Now handler looks like this, with the fromJust function because of the Maybe wrapper:

```
getManDetailsR :: ManifestationId -> Handler Html
getManDetailsR mid = do
    (_, user) <- requireAuthPair
    md <- runDB $ get404 mid
    loc <- runDB $ get404 $ fromJust(manifestationLocation md) -- and now use loc in template
    liftIO $ print (loc)
    defaultLayout $ do
        setTitle "Manifestation details"
        $(widgetFile "man-details")
```